# How does JVM parse command line arguments?

Tags: java, parsing, jvm, command-line-arguments

Could anyone explain me how exactly JVM parses string/arguments from command line and creates array of String (String[] args) from it? If possible I would actually like to see the code.

Let's say I have a compiled java program that takes input from command line:

`$ java Test Hi, now you "parse me" ""plea"se`

It creates the array with values like that:

```
 args[0] = Hi,
 args[1] = now
 args[2] = you
 args[3] = parse me
 args[4] = please
```

I assume that the text from the command line is passed as String to JVM, then JVM splits the string according to the some rules and creates String[] array from it.

By observation, the way I see it is like this:

It splits the whole input string from command line by space delimiter unless the space is between a pair of double quotes `"`. It considers double quotes `"` and `\` as special characters the same way bash does and do exactly the same with them as bash. So whenever it finds `"` it tries to match it with another `"` and everything between the pair of double quotes is considered as one String unless It's escaped by `\`.

Comment: The parsing is done by your shell not the jvm

Comment: Then why does it ignore single quotes `'`?

Comment: To correctly answer that, we'd need to know which shell you're using. If you're using Windows, that would likely be `cmd.exe`. If you're using Linux, that would likely be `bash`. Is it one of those, or some other shell?

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was using intellij to pass arguments and I incorrectly read that it's the equivalent of bash. @Andreas Don't you know about java parser which takes string input and parses it the same way like bash? So the output is String[] array? I need java parser which do exactly the same like bash with string input.Basically something like Apache CLI but with string input that handles quotes